# Why if condition not working in my AsyncTask onPostExecute

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask

i got success response in doinbackground() in AsyncTask. when i check the equalsignorecase on postExecute() its not entering inside. here below is my code.how can i move to next step, what was the issue please help me.

```
   class Service extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        String responseStr = null;
        String res="Failure";
        ProgressDialog pd;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pd.setMessage("Loading..");
            pd.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
          try {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Config.POST_URL);
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("loantype",mortageText));
                if(mortageText.equalsIgnoreCase("Refinanace"))
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("loanamount",h_borrow));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("esthomevalue",estimatedHM));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("creditscore",thirdViewBoxText));
                if(mortageText.equalsIgnoreCase("Refinanace"))
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("currentinterstrate",Integer.toString(intrest)));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname",firstNameText));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname",lastNameText));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address",streetAddressText));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",emailText));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city",cityText));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("state",stateText));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("zip",zipText));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone",phoneText));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("currentyinfha",militaryText));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("miltaryservice",militaryserviceText));

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));                  
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }

             }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return responseStr;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pd.cancel();
            if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("Success"))
            {
                dialogGreatNews();

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tested with `Log.d()` the actual content of `result` once it reaches `onPostExecute()`?

Comment: no i tested with Log.v() in doInBackGround()

Comment: Ok, but does it return the expected value?

Comment: white space issue. thanks for u r response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trim white space or check if new line character exists

```
if(result.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Success")) {

    dialogGreatNews();

}
```